# iphone dev add cell text to the same position point on UIView

Tags: iphone, tableview, cell

When i selected a cell, i want to add the text from the cell to the underlying UIView at the same position.

So the text in the UIView should be at the same position as the text in the cell.
I dont know how to map the cell origin to a UIView origin point.

Anyone any hints?

Comment: what do you mean by "underlying UIView?" is it the UIView you'll push onto the navigation stack when the cell is tapped?

Comment: @chrissr: that question seems unrelated, if I'm getting this one right.

Comment: have you found answer for this as i am also stucked in the same scenario.If yes how had u implemented that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIView's `convertPoint:fromView:` and `convertPoint:toView` (and the corresponding `convertRect:...`) to convert between coordinate systems.

Comment: Are you sure this also works with a uiscrollview, so this can convert a point from uitable y.2300 to a y value that fits between 0 and 480 (the UIView display height) because it only works if i dont scroll downwards.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right, you want to start by finding the position of the selected cell. For this, you can use the `rectForRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableView`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer you can do the following

`

```
CGRect rectInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    CGRect rectInSuperview = [tbldropdown convertRect:rectInTableView toView:[tbldropdown superview]];
```

`

Set the view frame as rectInSuperview.